# Remove parts of items in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, web-scraping, trim

I have data stored in a list, basically in the following format:

```
['http://www.website.com/category/apples',
'http://www.website.com/category/oranges',
'http://www.website.com/category/bananas',
'http://www.website.com/category/pears']
```

There are about 900 unique links contained within this list. I want to return the text after `category` (e.g. `apples`, `oranges`, etc.)

This probably is done through a `for` loop like the following, but I'm getting stuck with the right functions to use. This is what I have so far, basically. The list is saved in `links`.

```
for l in links:
    new_list = l.search('category')
    return l
```

How can I optimize what is essentially "trimming" each element in my list?

Comment: Regular expressions, man.

Comment: I don't get how that applies to this issue

Comment: or simply l[31:] if your links all have the same start.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['http://www.website.com/category/apples',
'http://www.website.com/category/oranges',
'http://www.website.com/category/bananas',
'http://www.website.com/category/pears']

li =  [ x[x.rindex('/')+1:] for x in l ]

print(li)
```

**OUTPUT**

['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'pears']

Comment: Probably want to search for the term `category` rather than just the slash. Works for the basic example, but the requirements of the original question mentioned things after category specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you use regular expressions.  You match your string against a regular expression that matches "category/", then use the parenthesis operator to return the characters after that.

```
import re
for l in links:
    m = re.match('.+/category/(.+)', l)
    new_list.append(m.group(1))
return new_list
```

To optimize, you can pre-compile the expression, which is probably worth doing for 900+ strings:

```
import re
cat = re.compile('.+/category/(.+)')
for l in links:
    new_list.append(cat.match(l).group(1))
return new_list
```

And this can be done in a list comprehension instead of a for loop:

```
import re
cat = re.compile('.+/category/(.+)')
return [cat.match(l).group(1) for l in links]
```

Comment: That matches `/apples` btw

Comment: Are you sure?  It returns as expected when I ran the test. It's not robust to lines that don't have "category/" in them, which I'd fix before actually using, but it works for me on the test data.

Comment: According to [regex101](https://regex101.com/), I was gonna post an answer but seeing two on here I didn't.